# identifying .mp3 not by name with shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to write a script that finds duplicate mp3's by content and not bf file name. I am wondering how one goes about seeing a file types inner data for the sake of comparison. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[`cmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp) can be used to compare binary files.

```
cmp file1.mp3 file2.mp3
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo "Matched"; fi
```

`cmp` command returns `0` if the files are same or else `-1`.

Comment: thank you that's perfect. If I had decided to adapt my code to compare all file types could I do something with a nested for loop comparing all files using the -t option?

Answer (score 2):

**This first command line** lists all files having same size and same `md5sum` from the current directory

```
find . -type f -printf '%11s ' -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | 
  sort | uniq -w44 --all-repeated=separate
```

**The second command line is**

- faster because it calculates `md5sum` solely for the files having the same size
- more robust because it handles filenames having special characters as 'space' or 'newline'

Therefore it is also more complex

```
find . -type f -printf '%11s %P\0' | 
  LC_ALL=C sort -z | 
  uniq -Dzw11 | 
  while IFS= read -r -d '' line
  do
    md5sum "${line:12}"
  done | 
  uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate | 
  tee duplicated.log
```

**Some explanations**

```
# Print file size/md5sum/name in one line (size aligned in 11 characters)
find . -printf '%11s ' -exec md5sum '{}' ';'

# Print duplicated lines considering the the first 44 characters only
# 44 characters = size (11 characters) + one space + md5sum (32 characters)
uniq -w44 --all-repeated=separate

# Print size and path/filename terminated by a null character
find . -printf '%11s %P\0'

# Sort lines separated by a null character (-z) instead of a newline character
# based on native byte value (LC_ALL=C) instead of locals
LC_ALL=C sort -z  

# Read lines separated by null character
IFS= read -r -d '' line

# Skip the first 12 characters (size and space) 
# in order to obtain the rest: path/filename
"${line:12}"
```

Comment: You are welcome ;-) It also helps me finding my duplicates files :-D. Thanks to your question, I improved a lot my duplicate file search. Thank you so much => +1 for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the files are really byte-to-byte equivalent, you can start searching for files of the same size. If their size is the same, you can investigate further (e.g. compare their `md5sum`). If the files just contain the same song, but use a different codec/compression/whatever, bash is probably not the right tool for the task.

Comment: haha thank you my next question was going to be if there is any approach using hash maps.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script for my photo but it can be used for other files.

- First I transfer pictures from my phone/camera to directory `newfiles`
- Then I run this script from my pictures root directory

  - On detection of duplicated files, the script keeps one file and moves the other ones to directory `../garbage`
  - The script moves in priority file from `newfiles`

**Caution:** This script does not compare file content, but it detects files having same size & name (this is OK for camera files). My other answer is based on content comparison (`md5sum`).

```
#!/bin/bash

# If a file from directory 'newfile' has same size & name
# that another file from another directory 
# then moves the file from 'newfile' to 'garbage'
find newfiles/ -type f -printf '%s %f\n' | 
while read SIZE f
do
   find . -name "$f" -size ${SIZE}c | 
     grep -v 'newfiles' && 
     find . -name "$f" -size ${SIZE}c -path '*newfiles*' -exec mv -v '{}' ../garbage ';' &&
     echo
done

# Detect all other duplicated files
# Keep the first occurrence and moves all other to 'garbage'
find . -type f -printf '%s %f\n' | 
  LC_ALL=C sort |  #LC_ALL=C disables locale => sort is faster
  uniq -dc      |  #keep duplicates and count number of occurrences 
  while read n SIZE f
  do
    echo -e "\n_____ $n files\t$SIZE bytes\tname: $f"
    find . -name "$f" -size ${SIZE}c |
       head -n 1 | 
       xargs mv -v -t ../garbage
  done
```